# Bounding holomorphic function at 0 given other bounds

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic function on a disk of radius $>1$ about the origin, and suppose that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for $z$ with $|z|=1$ and $\text{Re}(z)>0$ and $|f(z)|\leq 2$ for $z$ with $|z|=1$ and $\text{Re}(z)\leq 0$.

How does one show the bound $|f(0)|\leq \sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 5):

Look at $g(z) = f(z)f(-z)$. By assumption, $|g(z)| \le 2$ on the whole circle $|z|=1$. Then use the maximum modulus principle and conclude.

Comment: Ah, this is a clever trick, +1.

Comment: I deleted a similar question (of mine) after realizing the similarity.  I'm roughly familiar with the maximum modulus principle but could one of you be a little more explicit how this applies here

Comment: @Squirtle Which part needs filling in? $g$ is holomorpic, since $f$ is. The bound on $|g|$ comes from the assumptions (draw a little picture if you don't see it). Finally the maximum modulus principle shows that $|g(0)| = |f(0)|^2 \le 2$.

Comment: Light bulb moment....  I'm all mathed out for the day.